# when I write data in Initiator，why there exists read requests?

Tags: iscsi

Initiator using open-iscsi in linux.
when I launch a write request, the target gets a series of read requests and then a write request. why these requests exists?
I found these requests seem to be consistent with the request when the Initiator logged into the target.

Comment: Some ideas: If you have a filesystem on the device, your write may be reading filesystem metadata.  If the offset or length of your write is not evenly divisible by the block size (512 bytes), then the initiator may read data at the extents of the write so that the write can be extended to include the entire block.  If you're capturing packets just at the moment that the drive is attached to the system, you'll see Linux attempting to read partition tables.

Comment: I just use the NVME SSD directly.

Comment: Yes, please capture the ethernet traffic when *just* this behavior occurs.